# Map "Mainland China" to "China" for Chartkick graph in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

The Chartkick line

```
<% geo_chart Coronavirus.group(:country).count(:deaths) %>
```

creates a nice map that shows death count due to Coronavirus by country (using Google Charts).
The problem is that my database includes the country name "Mainland China" instead of "China."
Therefore, the death count for China is listed as zero, which is wrong.
How can I have Chartkick correctly interpret "Mainland China" as "China"?

Comment: update the key :D

Comment: Good idea.  I'll try to set Coronavirus.country to "China" where it equals "Mainland China" now.

Comment: Can you add the response of `Coronavirus.group(:country).count(:deaths)` in question?

Comment: Thanks Vishal.  I'm new to Rails.  This is data from 1/22 to 3/04.  After I do `coronaviri = Coronavirus.where(country: 'Mainland China')` and `coronaviri.update(country: 'China')`, I get `Coronavirus.group(:country).count(:deaths)` to be 1,106 for China.  In comparison, for US it is 496.  Again, these data are for 1/22 to 3/04.

Comment: Okay. so you resolved issue. right?

Comment: Yes, issue is resolved by renaming the key as you suggested.  Thanks for the tip!